# How to properly organize nodes and edges of a node-link diagram in python

Tags: python, graph, visualization, networkx

I have a dataframe that includes two columns (sender and recipient) that I want to display in the node-link diagram. It does appear but it is not showing properly. The values in the sender can appear in the recipient as well. There are also self-connected relations in the dataframe.

I'm very new to networkx so I am not sure what I can do to fix the positioning of the nodes.
I looked into the documentation and said I could change layouts for proper sizing and visualization. But **spring_layout()** is the best one and it is showing in a very messy manner.

Here is the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

#Creating a network graph
G = nx.Graph()

#Adding edges from panda series
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(emails, source='sender', target='recipient')

#Auto mapping for optimal positioning of the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

#Plotting
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=300, node_color="skyblue", node_shape="s", font_size='10', alpha=0.5, linewidths=60)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image]